# SGE set maximum number of nodes per user

Tags: cluster, quota, queue

I would like to limit the number of nodes a user can submit jobs to on a given queue. Is it possible?

For example, I have 5 nodes with 10 cores each, and I do not want a given user to be allowed to use the whole cluster, but 60% at the most (3 nodes).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a resource quota. Based on the amount of slots which makes it more dynamic to distribute jobs on the hosts, rather than specifying hosts.

```
root@host:~# qconf -srqs limit
{
   name         limit
   description  NONE
   enabled      TRUE
   limit        users {user} queues {my.q} to slots=30
}
```

You can create the resource quota with `qconf -arqs <quota-name>` and configure it.